# I have snap loops on my ssd. Doesn't this beat the purpose of using an ssd?

Tags: 18.04, ssd, snap, partitioning

I ran the `lsblk` command on the terminal.

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/296
loop1         7:1    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
loop2         7:2    0  42.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
loop3         7:3    0 181.1M  1 loop /snap/spotify/36
loop4         7:4    0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/61
loop5         7:5    0  54.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1074
loop6         7:6    0 149.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
loop7         7:7    0  54.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1098
loop8         7:8    0 149.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
loop9         7:9    0   4.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/501
loop10        7:10   0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/406
loop11        7:11   0  88.7M  1 loop /snap/core/7396
loop12        7:12   0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/317
loop13        7:13   0    89M  1 loop /snap/core/7713
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   238G  0 part /
```

These are the snap partitions on my drive. Every loop partition has `rotational` set to `1`. Does this affect the read/write speeds to these paritions? Or does the SSD read/write to these like it would the nvme paritions? Additionally, do these snap partitions affect the SSD's life in anyway? Is there anyway I can tell these applications to load from the nvme partition? This is my first question, I apologize if I sound stupid or have missed out on other existing answers.

Comment: Snaps load slower than applications installed by apt, so it's a good idea to leave the snap loops on the SSD.

Comment: The snap partitions are slow because `rotational` is set to 1?

Comment: Snaps load slowly because snap packages contain the application's dependencies and the application itself bundled together into one snap package, so there are more bits to load.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. If I compare loading snap packages from an ssd vs. snap packages from a hdd, they'll load faster on the ssd? Does having the `/sys/block/loop?/queue/rotational` being set to 1 impact the ssd's performance in anyway vs. it being set to 0? Additionally, these snap packages are set to `read-only`, so how and when are these updated?

Comment: Snaps load faster on an SSD. Snaps are updated automatically in the background separately from apt packages whenever updates for them become available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files from which the loop devices are mounted, are located on the SSD, then they will be read at roughly the same speed as any other data on the SSD. As the loops are read-only, they also will not severely affect the life span of the SSD.

As snaps are SquashFS files, reading of data may be slightly slower, due to needing to decompress data as they are being read into memory.

Comment: This is intersesting. So setting the `/sys/block/<partition_name>/queue/rotational` to `1` on an SSD doesn't impact performance? Yes, them being `read-only` shouldn't affect the lifespan of an SSD. Even if certain snap packages get updated frequently, it shouldn't affect the SSD's health to a noticeable degree, right? Considering how small the packages are.

Comment: Is there a way to give snap packages the freedom to be stored on disk uncompressed?

Comment: A surprising observation is that these snap loops don't show up on gparted!

Comment: They are loopback mounts, not partitions, so they will not show up in partitioning tools. They are not actual disks. The "rotational" property has nothing to do with performance, though having it set to true for loopback mounts which are not sourced from files on rotational disks is probably a bug. And no, you can't store them on disk uncompressed.